# Google+ Fan Page Logo Competition

Tags: discussion, google+

Because our current Google+ logo doesn't exactly fit the trademark guidelines we need a new one!

The good news is, SE have offered to give away **one amazing swag package full of Stack Exchange and Ask Ubuntu goodies** to the person who comes up with the next logo for [our Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/107921963368679288414)!

These are the rules:

- The logo must be original and your own work
- You need to provide a large size (512×512 would be nice, preferably SVG)

  - Make sure the logo renders nicely at 44×44, 48×48, and 200×200 pixels
- The logo must not be too similar to the Ask Ubuntu or Stack Exchange logo ([see more](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance))
- Since we might use the logo elsewhere too, a transparent background would be helfpul
- One entry per per person. If you're unhappy with a previous submission, and you want to change it, consider deleting your old answer and posting a new one.

The contest closes on Sunday, 20:00 UTC, and the winner is the entry with the highest score.

So fire up Inkscape, the Gimp, read [SE's trademark guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) and [Canonical's trademark policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy), and let's see what you can come up with!

---

### We have a winner

Thanks a lot to everyone for participating, and to Octavian Damiean for posting the winning entry. The logo is [on our page now](https://plus.google.com/107921963368679288414)!

Comment: Are we allowed multiple entries?

Comment: It's one entry per person, sorry for adding that late.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wanted to keep it simple because I just prefer simplicity in design.

<sub>512x512</sub>
[image: Ask Ubuntu Google Plus logo 512x512]

<sub>200x200</sub>
[image: Ask Ubuntu Google Plus logo 200x200]

This is 48x48, 44x44 and 16x16 accordingly. 16x16 just to show you how a favicon would look like.

<sub>48x48</sub>
[image: Ask Ubuntu Google Plus logo 48x48]

<sub>44x44</sub>
[image: Ask Ubuntu Google Plus logo 44x44]

<sub>16x16</sub>
[image]

Additional material:

- [Inkscape SVG source - 2048x2048](http://ubuntuone.com/5VVj81Ljv7JgRNXkjRSIFf)
- [Plain SVG version - 2048x2048](http://ubuntuone.com/6bO0xfyBAoyfyF2VALukeu)
- [PNG version - 2048x2048](http://ubuntuone.com/5LlQqzwZ8Ghat691tFl5EK)

*The logo is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution license. Ask Ubuntu has the full rights to use it as needed with or without attribution.*

Comment: actually is very a very simple design and it's very easy to identify with askubuntu. That's the point, right? =D

Comment: Right, the connection between Ask Ubuntu and Google Plus should be easily identifiable.

Comment: Look's like a Hospital's logo. (I like it)

Comment: Great! I love it. Everything is said by it without being overloaded.

Comment: Simple and powerful

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback guys. :)

Comment: Congratz @OctavianDamiean!

Answer (score 10):

In the spirit of the sites humble beginnings, my own lack of artistic talent and etc, I present the Crayon Logo:

[image]

Unfortunately, due to the medium I used, I cannot produce a SVG, nor the suggested sizes - however, I can and will do a proper scan.

Comment: I am sorry but cannot vote for this in good faith because I am still waiting on my PONY!

Comment: @lqlarry Have a pony good sir. - http://images.hellokids.com/_uploads/_tiny_galerie/200811/pony-coloring-page-source_by1.jpg

Comment: The best way to buy a vote.  I will vote early and vote often now.  Congratulations by the way.

Comment: Taking the time to add cut-and-paste letters instead of simply drawing them on makes it look a lot more professional, IMO.

Comment: Looks Nice, Add a +1

Comment: Nice dadaistic performance, by the way. Live handicraft, often better than cold pragmatism. Great picture, jrg!

Comment: @swift My pleasure, it was the first time I've had reason to pick up crayons in years, and I found I really enjoyed it. :)

Comment: It's great :) mimic typographic looks very cinematic.
If replace background to AU circle balloon it can be worthy solution for some needs, or just for new idea.

Answer (score 9):

[image]
[200 x 200 PNG with 8-bit alpha channel](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/askubuntu_contest/askubuntu1_200.png)

[image]
[48 x 48 PNG with 8-bit alpha channel](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/askubuntu_contest/askubuntu1_48.png)

[image]
[44 x 44 PNG with 8-bit alpha channel](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/askubuntu_contest/askubuntu1_44.png)

---

You can download the SVG version of the logo above here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/askubuntu_contest/askubuntu1.svg

Comment: You can see what the G+ page would look like with this logo by clicking here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BpB9J.png

Comment: Do you think you can do something about the slightly skewed _Ubuntu_?

Comment: @OctavianDamiean: The "Ask" uses the Ubuntu font and the "Ubuntu" uses the Ubuntu Condensed font.

Comment: Ah, that explains it then. :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: 512 by 512]

[512 by 512 without transparency, white background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv6RD.png)

[image: 200 by 200]

[200 by 200 without transparency, white background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oniyo.png)

[image: 48 by 48]

[48 by 48 without transparency, white background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfe9O.png)

[image: 44 by 44]

[44 by 44 without transparency, white background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyepR.png)

I apologize but I cannot generate an SVG with the tool that I am using. I can, however, give you a super high resolution version as well as a PDF for files, and I can give you a link to a Sliderocket presentation which can be as big as your screen size. That is all I can offer for alternate options. Sorry about the surrounding white space, even though it can be easily deleted through GIMP or your favorite image editor.

Sliderocket presentation (Rev 3): http://portal.sliderocket.com/OMS/My-Presentation-3

Super high resolution (Rev 2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuW3T.png

Super high resolution with only 8 layers of dots (Rev 1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/455ac.png

PDF (Rev 3): http://cboos.com/My%20Presentation%203.pdf

Super High resolution with transparency and 8 layers of dots (Rev 1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ57z.png

XCF (Rev 1): http://www.cboos.com/image.xcf

Changelog: Rev 1: Original Image.
Rev 2: Added another layer of dots on top to make it look more complete when viewed in a square resolution.
Rev 3: Seperated "Stack" and "Exchange" and altered the color of the fourth color of dots to make the color transition more smooth. Changed the color of the dot in the bottom left hand corner to be a darker orange. Increased the font size of "Ask Ubuntu" so the text would be readable at lower resolutions. Got rid of two random dots that somehow wound up at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: The text is way too small from 200x200 downwards.

Comment: Yeah, the text doesn't matter that much anyway.

Comment: You can see the text, depends on screen res.

Comment: It might still make sense to improve the readability of the text in low resolutions. Also note that it may be rendered on poor screens and then the result is worse.

Comment: Does Google Plus allow different images for different sizes (44 by 44 is different then the 200 by 200 picture)?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of downvotes. Could someone please explain how they think this logo could be improved?

Comment: Also, in Rev 3, made the font size bigger to allow easier viewing of the text at lower resolutions.

Comment: I made a screenshot. The logo looks especially nice on the sidebar, it blends in well with the white background. See the image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/xWmwO.png .

Answer (score 6):

Edited to make text visible even at smaller sizes *(44x44 & 48x48)*

[Inkscape's SVG file hosted @ U1](http://ubuntuone.com/3ikTAsPWNzqGhddwO5dpFS)

[512x512](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XolME.png):

[image: 512x512]

[200x200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3jT6.png):

[image: 200x200]

[48x48](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7tvp.png)

[image: 48x48]

[44x44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ru3P.png)

[image: 44x44]

Feel free to use the design if you can salvage it to make it better :)

Comment: Personally, I think it might look better with the text around the top half, instead of around the left side. Just a suggestion.  :)

Comment: @John I originally tried that, but wasn't a fan of it. Looked very generic *(imho)* hence put it across the left :)

Comment: I like this one, and the text on the left is a nice style to me.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternate colour scheme and layout**

### [image]

[image: main]

[512 by 512 without transparency,with ring,coloured background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQRg.png)

[image: 200*200]

[200 by 200 without transparency,with ring,coloured background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR0iu.png)

[image: 48*48]

[48 by 48 without transparency,with ring,coloured background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpD9I.png)

I will add other versions later.

---

### Transparents

[image: stx]

[512 by 512 with transparency,with ring,no background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqqr2.png)

[image: str]

[200 by 200 with transparency,with ring,no background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqqr2.png)

[image: stn]

[48 by 48 with transparency,with ring,no background, PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX6Ux.png)

Comment: Mainly because of the visual noise created by an inappropriate mixture of colors and the layout problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Better than Gold]

- An idea a little bit out of competition :) Enjoy, **Au** !

  [au-gplus.svg](http://ubuntuone.com/4qn8VxLwDrMIor7pGkLFat)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no designer, but I thought I'd give it a try anyway.
Anyone who can take the same idea and do it better is welcome to try. :)
There's transparency behind the outer gradient. IMO it also looks fine on a black background.

Here's the [album](https://picasaweb.google.com/111247824106764957942/AskUbuntu).
Here's the modified version:
[image: 512x512]

Comment: Here is some feedback. The Ask Ubuntu logo and the Ubuntu Circle of Friends are skewed. The gradient is way to much. It also generally has no connection to Google Plus.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Thanks for the feedback. I put the gradient there to let the Ubuntu Circle show on white background. And it's skewed to fit around the speech bubble, but I can make a more circular one as well. I guess the text can be changed to "+ask" to signify connection to Google Plus.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean See if you like the modified version better :)

Comment: SVG: http://ubuntuone.com/3Mrhzp1kwyH3YtcIdRODN8

Comment: Wow, I really like this one!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PNG export of my first attempt with Inkscape (I've never succesfully made a logo in my life, let alone with Inkscape).
[image: My attempt]

The PNG export looks fine... The problem is that when I try to save it as an SVG file, the horizontal rectangle disappears. Even odder is that it looks fine in this post as well, but not on my computer when I try to open it with Inkscape again...
SVG file: [image: SVG file]